# Passing lambda function as parameter and give its parameter in the method body

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a method where I handle some pagination logic of a plugin;

```
public async Task<JsonResult> DataPagination()
{
    List<GLAccountModel> glAccounts = await HttpClientHelper.GetListHttpResponseAsync<GLAccountModel>(httpBaseAdress, "GLAccount", "GetAll");

    var (filteredResultCount, totalRecord) = DataTableHelper.ManageDataTable(glAccounts, Request, x => x.Name.Contains());

    return Json(new { data = glAccounts, draw = Request["draw"], recordsTotal = totalRecord, recordsFiltered = filteredResultCount });
}
```

Here, I am passing the lambda function `x => x.Name.Contains()` to the `ManageDataTable` method. Here is the implementation of `ManageDataTable`method;

```
public static (int, int) ManageDataTable<TModel>(List<TModel> models, HttpRequestBase request, Func<TModel, bool> lambdaExpression) where TModel : class
{               
    string search = request["search[value]"];//arama

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        models = models.Where(lambdaExpression).ToList();
    }

    return (filteredResultCount, totalRecord);
}
```

I want to be able to give the parameter of `Contains()` method in the body of `ManageDataTable()` method rather then sending it with the parameter itself. To be more clear, I want to receive the lambda function `x => x.Name.Contains()` from `ManageDataTable()`, and inside the body of `ManageDataTable()` I want to be able to give a parameter to the `Contains()` method which is a part of my lambda function. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: We need to know more about what you're trying to achieve. Is `search` the value you'd want to pass in? Would you *always* just want a string?

Comment: It will be always string. The value of "search" will be determined inside the body of `ManageDataTable`, so I want to set the parameter of `Contains` method inside `ManageDataTable` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options I can imagine here, in terms of changing the method parameter. You could either make it a `Func<string, Func<TModel, bool>>` like this:

```cs
public static (int, int) ManageDataTable<TModel>(
    List<TModel> models,
    HttpRequestBase request,
    Func<string, Func<TModel, bool>> filterProvider)
    where TModel : class
{
    string search = request["search[value]"];//arama

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        var filter = filterProvider(search);
        models = models.Where(filter).ToList();
    }

    return (filteredResultCount, totalRecord);
}
```

You'd call that like this:

```cs
DataTableHelper.ManageDataTable(glAccounts, Request,
    search => model => model.Name.Contains(search));
```

This approach is effectively a higher-ordered method. Alternatively, you could take a `Func<TModel, string, bool>` like this:

```cs
public static (int, int) ManageDataTable<TModel>(
    List<TModel> models,
    HttpRequestBase request,
    Func<TModel, string, bool> filter)
    where TModel : class
{
    string search = request["search[value]"];//arama

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        models = models.Where(model => filter(model, search)).ToList();
    }

    return (filteredResultCount, totalRecord);
}
```

You'd call that like this:

```cs
DataTableHelper.ManageDataTable(glAccounts, Request,
    (model, search) => model.Name.Contains(search));
```

It doesn't matter very much which of those you use - but it's worth making sure you understand both of them.

Comment: Second approach looks way more better. Thanks for the perfect examples.